# Is it Possible to Name the Azure Network Watcher?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-group, azure-bicep

When I created an Azure virtual network, it automatically creates a Network Watcher called `NetworkWatcher_canadacentral` for me in its own resource group called `NetworkWatcherRG`.

My question is whether its possible to give the Network Watcher and the resource group it gets created in a custom name. I'm using Pulumi to Create my virtual network but answers showing ARM/Bicep/Terraform are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name it whatever you want as long as it meets the [naming requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftnetwork) which is 1-80 chars, Alphanumerics, underscores, periods, and hyphens. Start with alphanumeric. End alphanumeric or underscore.

### Terraform

In Terraform you just give the Network Watcher resource name whatever you want like so:

```
resource "azurerm_network_watcher" "app1_traffic" {
  name                = "MyAwesomeNetworkWatcherName"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.application1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.application1.name
}
```

### PowerShell

In PowerShell the command is:

```
New-AzNetworkWatcher -Name "MyNetworkWatcherName" -ResourceGroupName "secstuff" -Location "East US 2"
```

### Pulumi

From what I see on the [Pulumi docs](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/network/networkwatcher/) Network Watcher does take a name parameter.

[image]

Comment: I am not creating a network watcher explicitly. One is created for me when I create a virtual network. I'm trying to figure out how I can control the naming of it.

Comment: If it's being created automatically, then I would guess your subscription has the **Deploy network watcher when virtual networks are created** policy assigned.  You will need to disable this policy if you want to change the default Network Watcher name.

Comment: You could modify the policy to put the Network Watcher elsewhere.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the policy through ARM/Bicep/Terraform/Pulumi since it seems to be a default in Azure? Do I need to do anything to connect the network watcher with the virtual network?

Comment: That's not how policy was designed to be used.  Policies are implemented to ensure compliance and if you could easily disable/circumvent them it wouldn't do much good to have them.  You can reverse a policy that is created via Terraform easily but if the policy was created outside then you need to use Powershell or the CLI to remove policy.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to do anything to connect the network watcher with the virtual network?

Comment: No, it is automatically enabled for any VNET created in the same region as then watcher, nothing to connect or configure.  You can opt-out of the automatic enablement but this impacts the entire subscription and will require a support ticket to re-enable.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-create#opt-out-of-network-watcher-automatic-enablement